# How is search done when reading or writing a file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

I have following code in my app as given at end of this post.

When the directory `C:\xyz\vb\` is empty or has very few files, then the code is lightning fast, but I am not so sure if it will still be as fast in a high traffic website, where not only many users would access files under this folder, but also there could be many files under this folder.  No two users would access the same file at same time, but there could be thousands of these user files in above folder.

**Question**:

How do each of these methods - `ReadAllText` and `WriteAllLines` in code below perform searching for the given file, and does reading and writing become slower as number of files goes up in the folder being accessed? My initial guess is that these methods would need to find the given file and therefore will become slower as number of files goes up.

```
//read a give file
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\xyz\vb\WriteText.txt");
//write to a given file
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:xyz\vb\WriteLines.txt", lines);
```

Comment: Read the Remarks section in [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Steve, Thanks for the tip. In my case I need to read all lines and not line by line. What I am really concerned about is whether these methods will be slower as number of files becomes large.

Comment: The NTFS file system is pretty efficient and finding a file by filename. Honestly, this really comes down to a hardware question. If you have thousands of file requests going on at once, all to a single drive, and possibly fragmented, that's going to be your bottleneck, not C#.

Comment: @Steve and concurrent access (if the read head is somewhere else on the platter, it takes time to physically move to the sector you want)

Comment: @Steve, Both the methods that I have in my code, will need to first find an existing file, before writing or reading lines. So search is always going to be there when these methods are called.

Comment: @dman2306, But doesn't C# need to run some code to find a file, even though there are hardware factors like fragmentation etc. that can slow it down?

Comment: @Sunil it's not C# code, that's handled much lower level by the file system. It uses a tree based index. It's not iterating through the directory. I have directories with 1million+ files (don't ask) and opening a file and reading it is no slower than in directories with 2 files. See http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-ebook/ntfs-index-record-and-contents.htm for how NTFS works.

Comment: @dman2306, Ok. So C# code may be calling some Windows OS API. That's great for my app since its going to be responsive. Could you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make file system calls in C#, under the covers, the .NET Framework is calling Windows OS API calls. Meaning, C# isn't "searching" for the file you're requesting, it's merely passing your request to native Windows API calls which in turn pass it to the File System. NTFS is very efficient at finding files. It does not iterate through a directory. Rather, it stores the files in a B-tree based index. This means finding the file you requested is almost instantaneous. Suffice it to say, a directory with a few thousand files in it is handled by NTFS very efficiently. You'll notice almost no difference between that and if it were the only file in the directory.

For a little more in depth explanation of how NTFS does the indexing, see [this link](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-ebook/ntfs-index-record-and-contents.htm).